# 27" CinemaDisplay with (non Bootcamp) Windows 7

Tags: cinema-display

I've seen various posts around the net that getting my 27" CinemaDisplay working with a native install of Windows 7 is apparently possible, but I cannot seem to get this working.

I have a Radeon HD 5770 in my PC: [http://www.amazon.com/ATI-RADEON-VIDEO-GRAPHICS-0GCJ42/dp/B005F6SMOU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005F6SMOU)

This card has a DisplayPort socket which I am connecting to my monitor with: http://www.frys.com/product/8001294?site=sr:SEARCH:MAIN_RSLT_PG

Does anyone have any info on how exactly they have this working?

I've downloaded the BootCamp 3.1 and 3.2 EXE's, but they both require 3.0 to run. I cannot find 3.0 online anywhere.

I've used the Boot Camp Assistant on my iMac running Mavericks, and installed the drivers it downloads to a USB key.
Running the setup.exe in the WindowsSupport directory and also running setup.exe in the BootCamp directory both immediately
start, then error with: "The installed encountered errors before Boot Camp could be configured".

If I go to the Drivers/Apple/ section, under either dir I can install the "AppleDisplayInstaller64.exe" just fine and it says the Apple driver is installed,
but my monitor does not turn on.

Also downloading "BootCamp5.1.5640.zip" from the Apple website and trying to run setup.exe states: "This version of Boot Camp is not intended for this computer model"

Is there *any* way to fix this? This just seems to be a driver issue.

Is it because my card doesn't have a native Mini DisplayPort and the adapter is causing an issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what is your problem connected with, I'd rather try connecting another monitor to the videocard you have so that it could be possible to check whether your DisplayPort is working or not?

As to the bootcamp install on Windows the following worked well for me:

in the folder BootCamp\Drivers\Apple BootCamp.msi is located.
Try launching it with Admin privileges using context menu